# Cannot start the apache2 server on my ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, apache2, 20.04, php

I have installed apache2 web server on my PC, after installation I started the server and used it for couple of days. But now when I need to work with it I was not being able to start the server.

I didn't add anything on my .conf files.

I used this command:

```bsh
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start 
# or 
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

But nothing works.

After executing

```bsh
sudo systemctl status apache2.conf
```

it shows the following error:

```
Jul 19 12:58:56 nasirul-H81M-D2V systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 19 12:58:56 nasirul-H81M-D2V apachectl[21219]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log
Jul 19 12:58:56 nasirul-H81M-D2V apachectl[21219]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at />
Jul 19 12:58:56 nasirul-H81M-D2V apachectl[21219]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Jul 19 12:58:56 nasirul-H81M-D2V apachectl[21202]: Action 'start' failed.
Jul 19 12:58:56 nasirul-H81M-D2V apachectl[21202]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jul 19 12:58:56 nasirul-H81M-D2V systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 19 12:58:56 nasirul-H81M-D2V systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 19 12:58:56 nasirul-H81M-D2V systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Mainly it shows that **configuration failed**

But how to do it? I have updated the `apache2.conf` file on `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` directory added

```
ServerName localhost 
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
```

Under the Global Configuration, but nothing can prevent the error.
After doing the `apache2ctl configtest` on apache2 directory this shows

```
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:2
AH00014: Configuration check failed
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: *"The Apache error log may have more information."* So what does the log say (add relevant parts to your question).

Comment: @xenoid This might be tricky in this special case, because according to the error message Apache can't write its logs ;)

Comment: No offense meant, but in many cases it really helps to actually _read_ the error messages ;) `No such file or directory` tells you, there's some file or directory missing that Apache would like to use. `Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log` tells you which directory it is and what Apache would like to use it for. The second error message is similar.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your reply 
but sadly i just deleted apache2 from my system on ubuntu, i am using lampp now. But the problem was that the apache2 couldn't been able to create a directory or get access to it. 
Thank you guys